# Prestashop 1.7 starter theme, assets in theme.yml is not working

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, smarty, prestashop

I'm using the starter theme for Prestashop 1.7 https://github.com/PrestaShop/StarterTheme

Reading the documentation I found that I can add a js/css file for specific templates editing the `theme.yml` file, simply adding (just for example):

```
assets:
  css:
    all:
      - id: bootstrap-style
        path: assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
  js:
    product:
      - id: jquery
        path: assets/js/jquery.min.js
        priority: 200
        position: bottom
```

but it doesn't work.

Here is the doc: http://developers.prestashop.com/themes/assets/index.html

Any idea?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved.

FYI here is the solution: https://github.com/PrestaShop/StarterTheme/issues/181#issuecomment-288043923

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since the link provided in the initial accepted answer is no longer valid (returns 404), here's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54736696) posted in another question by [@Arnaud Scoté](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11075766/arnaud-scot%C3%A9):

> If you want reload your configuration :
>
> 1. Modify your theme.yml
> 2. Delete the file into ROOT_FOLDER/config/themes/your theme/shop*.json
> 3. Refresh your page,
>      prestashop going to regenerate the config json file for your theme

Comment: There isn't any shop*.json file